# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) after mysql -u root -p

Tags: mysql

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and MySQL version 8.0.30. I start mysql using the command:

```
systemctl start mysql.service
```

When I run `systemctl status mysql.service` I get this output:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-11-27 10:32:12 CET; 10min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
    Process: 41445 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 41484 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 39 (limit: 6969)
     Memory: 395.6M
        CPU: 5.184s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─41484 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Then I do:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It should now ask me for my password but it doesn't. Instead I get:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to sign in as the `root` account on MySQL, you must use `sudo mysql`. There is no requirement to state the user or password, as a system admin already has full access to the server. This change was made to MySQL 7 years ago 

Comment: I believe that is the right answer. Thank you @matigo